# function is not defined at HTMLAnchroElement.onclick, Kendo UI

Tags: javascript, jquery, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I have set of buttons on Kendo Toolbar alongside with my custom button called Command.

```
 toolbar_click: function () {
            console.log("Funcion successfully called");
    },

 initEditor_inline: function (elEdit) {
            var vm = this;

            var wgEdit = $(elEdit).data("kendoEditor");

            var isBodyCtrl = (this.editorCtrlId["Body"] == elEdit.id);

            var arrTools = [];

            if (isBodyCtrl) {
                arrTools = [

                    "bold",
                    "italic",
                    "underline",
                    "strikethrough",  
                        {
                            name: "Add",
                            template: '<a class="k-button" href="\\#" onclick="return toolbar_click()">Command</a>',

                        }
                    , 

                "fontName", "fontSize", "foreColor", "backColor",
                "justifyLeft", "justifyCenter", "justifyRight",
                "insertUnorderedList", "insertOrderedList", "indent", "outdent",
                "createLink", "unlink", "insertImage",
                "subscript", "superscript",
                    "createTable", "tableWizard", "addRowAbove", "addRowBelow", "addColumnLeft", "addColumnRight", "deleteRow",
                    "deleteColumn",
                "viewHtml", "cleanFormatting"];
            }
```

Now, I am trying to call toolbar_click() on click of Command button but I am getting

> Uncaught ReferenceError: toolbar_click is not defined
>       at HTMLAnchorElement.onclick

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`toolbar_click()` seems to be defined as an object property, so you need to specify - unless it is defined in the `window` object - which object it is in order to call it. Example:

```
events = {
    toolbar_click: function () {
            console.log("Funcion successfully called");
    },
}
```

Then..

```
<a class="k-button" href="\\#" onclick="return events.toolbar_click()">Command</a>
```